# How to bind child data grid with data from code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to use multilevel data grid in wpf application like nested data grid or 
with expand and collapse button
for multilevel data grid i have use following code :

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Name" Binding="{Binding JobName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Number" Binding="{Binding JobNumber}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Name="Employees" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

    </DataGrid>
```

How to bind child level data grid from code behind in wpf.
FOr parent level data grid i have use following code:

```
DataTable smb1 = new DataTable();
        InitializeComponent();
        smb1.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", typeof(string));
        smb1.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION_STATUS", typeof(string));
        smb1.Columns.Add("DATE", typeof(DateTime));
        smb1.Columns.Add("PERIOD", typeof(string));
        smb1.Columns.Add("MACHINE", typeof(string));
        smb1.Rows.Add("PRODUCT", "Clothes", DateTime.Now, "David", "SMB1");
        smb1.Rows.Add("PRODUCT NUMBER", "Shoes", DateTime.Now, "David", "SMB1");
        smb1.Rows.Add("BATCH NUMBER", "Enebrel", DateTime.Now, "Sam", "SMB1");
        SMB1.ItemsSource = smb1.DefaultView;
```

Comment: And where and how is DataTable2 defined?

Comment: <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Name="Employees" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmployeeName}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

Comment: Where is the IsChecked and EmploteeName property that you are trying to bind to...? And please don't add code in the comments field. Edit your question instead.